# Why i am getting server error: not implemented : LWT in cassandra cql?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

i am using cassandra cql, i want to use light weight transaction (LWT) for my insert and update query but it gives error
Server Error: Not implemented: LWT
Can any one help please?

Comment: Maybe you're sending the request to a C* cluster with version < 3.0 ?

Comment: i have latest version of C* cluster, i don' know where the issue is, i have tried to find the solution on google but couldn't find

Comment: what the consistency level you configured, I suspect that it should either be SERIAL or LOCAL_SERIAL

Comment: Current consistency level is ONE.

Comment: Try changing it to SERIAL, for more info: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_tunable_consistency_c.html?hl=light%2Ctransaction going to bed, good luck & please update this thread if it helped, I'm curious!

Comment: It's not working, i have tried all consistencies, bad luck i have

Comment: Can you please upgrade your question with proper query and error message that you receive from cqlsh? Also executing a `show version` and adding it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Happen to see this post when I search for `Light Weighted Txn`. Scylla currently doesn't support it; related Github Issue: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/1359